# how can we call a local json dile in our Vue app ? if we are using a CDN link for Vue

Tags: json, vue.js

How can we use a local JSON data file in  Vue app if we are using a CDN link for Vue. please help. i am unable to use my JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one of the easiest way is doing an XHR request to get it. (Download it basically)